# How to auto generate text with alphabets in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to mass-produce a list such as,

Type A
Type B
Type C
..
...
....
Type Z

How can I do it with Excel? I will be generating not just "type" but any other text combined with an alphabet on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps like this:

```
="Type " & CHAR(ROW(A65))
```

[image]

Or if you're dragging across instead of down:

```
="Type " & CHAR(COLUMN(BM1))
```

Comment: Ha... thanks, glad to help out. Just note, this works up to "Z" but you'd have to do differently if you're going past that, e.g. AA, AB, AC or whatever.